# How do I create thor::group generators as args of my_command

Tags: ruby, rubygems, generator, thor

In my gem I'd like to have a an executable command with args like so:

```
foo generate project
foo generate config
foo say_hi
```

So I made

*foo/bin/foo*

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'foo'
Foo::Foo.start
```

And the Foo file in *foo/lib/thor/foo.rb*

```
module Foo 
  class Foo < Thor

    desc "generate [WHAT]"
    def generate(*args)

    end

    desc "say_hi"
    def say_hi(*args)
       ....
    end

  end
end
```

And *foo/lib/thor/generators/project.rb*
And *foo/lib/thor/generators/config.rb*

Where I'd like to specify classes inherited from Thor::Group like katz examples ...

```
module Foo
  module Generators
    class Project < Thor::Group
      include Thor::Actions
      ....
    end
  end
end
```

So my question is: How do I set things up so that I can call those generators from the executable like:

```
foo generate config
```

Am I on the right track even? Ideally, typing `foo` on its own should give help for `say_hi` and for all the generators.

Comment: looks like Thor#register may help. I'll persevere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had trouble getting this to work at first, too. Here's the pattern that I've started using:

$ cat cli.rb

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'rubygems'
require 'thor'
require 'thor/group'

module CLI
  class Greeter < Thor::Group
    def say_hi
      say "Hi"
    end
    def say_goodbye
      say "Goodbye"
    end
  end
end

module CLI
  class Crud < Thor
    desc 'create', 'Creates a sub-thing'
    def create
      say "Creating a sub-thing"
    end

    desc 'delete', 'Deletes a sub-thing'
    def delete
      say "Deleting a sub-thing"
    end

  end
end

module CLI
  class Root < Thor
    register CLI::Greeter, 'greet', 'greet', 'Executes a multi-step subtask'
    register CLI::Crud, 'crud', 'crud [COMMAND]', 'Delegates to a sub-command'
  end
end

CLI::Root.start
```

$ ./cli.rb

```
Tasks:
  cli.rb crud [COMMAND]  # Delegates to a sub-command
  cli.rb greet           # Executes a multi-step subtask
  cli.rb help [TASK]     # Describe available tasks or one specific task
```

$ ./cli.rb greet

```
Hi
Goodbye
```

$ ./cli.rb crud

```
Tasks:
  cli.rb crud create          # Creates a sub-thing
  cli.rb crud delete          # Deletes a sub-thing
  cli.rb crud help [COMMAND]  # Describe subcommands or one specific subcommand
```

$ ./cli.rb crud create

```
Creating a sub-thing
```

$ ./cli.rb crud delete

```
Deleting a sub-thing
```

Comment: This looks good, thanks! And it seems you have no issues getting the help to be properly formatted. I managed to get things working but had to parse the help string to remove colons. I'll use your solution in future.